# Export Active Directory from 2008R2 to Samba 4 DC

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I know that they can co-exist, but is it possible to export the contents of an AD into an Ubuntu server Domain Controller that's setup with Samba4 AD?

I'm hoping to reduce disruption as we take down a Server 2008R2 DC with DHCP/DNS/AD and migrate to Ubuntu.

Ideally, I'd like users to be able to keep their Windows profile and just have the new domain name match the old one.  I am not concerned about group policy not being migrated.

I am hoping to migrate and then turn off AD on the 2008 VM and turn on Ubuntu.

Is the best option to just recreate all users on the new AD, get everyone to sign into a new Windows profile. It's 8.1/10 end users about 25 people.

Any tips or advice would be great!

Comment: Are the down votes just people chanting 'Micro-soft, micro-soft' ? This is a financial decision, obviously it would be easier to keep MS Server. Maybe if we weren't paying $450 per person per year just to have people on our server for basic file access etc...

Comment: I down voted because your working method for achieving your goal is ludicrous - there's a well documented path for achieving what you're trying to do and you seem to be going out of your way to avoid it. Other than that, I don't care if you use Windows, Linux or OS/2 or an unexpanded commodore Vic 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the ADMT if you wanted to create a new domain, but as you want to have a minimal impact on your user base then the logical thing to do is to join the samba host as a new domain controller (DC) in the same AD domain.

After that the AD objects should be replicated to the new DC and you should replicate the sysvol and netlogon shares manually or with robocopy.

The whole process is documented in the samba wiki: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Join_an_additional_Samba_DC_to_an_existing_Active_Directory

Comment: After the replication is finished, I can take the original DC offline then? I'm not familiar with sysvol.  This is just AD related information store, not shared files/folders?  Thanks.

Comment: yes, after everything is in sync you can take the original DC offline. The sysvol and netlogon shares are where the gpo/login scripts are kept. You should probably indicate somewhere that the samba DC has the FSMO roles, but I have no idea on how to do that with samba AD (should not be very different though).